# How to get a confidence level with cpplint?

Tags: c++, c++17, cpplint

How do I get a confidence value from cpplint?

--verbose = 0
doesn't do anything for me

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you are running the command? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `cpplint 1.5.5`. I believe the confidence value displays per default when using it:

**Input:**
`cpplint memory_management.h`

**Ouput:** Both have a confidence level of `[5]`

```
memory_management.h:0:  No copyright message found.  You should have a line: "Copyright [year] <Copyright Owner>"  [legal/copyright] [5]
memory_management.h:0:  No #ifndef header guard found, suggested CPP variable is: _HOME_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_H_  [build/header_guard] [5]
Done processing memory_management.h
Total errors found: 2
```